# Ascii and lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog and can't find any example working with ASCII code and lists so can you help me with the assignment or give me some materials?

I have the assignment to create a predicate little_letter/2 that will count how many small letters are in the string. (ASCII code between 97 and 122).

and the second assignment is to create a predicate multiply_list/3 which will multiply every number in the list with a given number and return new list

Comment: [GitHub](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/useful-prolog-references/1089#github-24) has lots of quality Prolog code if you know were to look. However there are many more bad examples of Prolog code thus the list in the reference.

Answer (score 1):

> can't find any example working with ASCII code and lists so can you help me with the assignment or give me some materials?

Open [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/) or SWI Prolog and query `?- apropos(string).`, you'll find `string_code/3`, `string_chars/2`, `string_codes/2`, and more.

Pick one, and query `?- help(string_chars).` and see the help. Try them interactively, see what they do.

ASCII codes are small numbers, so any lists and numbers tutorial will work for them, e.g. [Learn Prolog Now](http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/lpn//lpnpage.php?pageid=online) chapters on recursion, lists, arithmetic, more lists.